# How to load dynamic data on rowExpander click?

Tags: oracle-jet

How to implement dynamic data loading on click of expander row icon.

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=rowExpander&demo=tableRowExpander

Comment: If you are asking about loading dynamic data in place of `Task 1`, that data is coming from ProjectData.json. You need to create json with your data and load the same.

Answer (score 0):

In few cases, It is not possible to load all children data in JSON if we have huge data.

so on click of expanding the row, can we send a request to the server and get children items and display under respective parent items. As per documentation provided by Oracle jet is completely dealing with hard-coded JSON only with complete data.